# Mac ZSH option to open file via index?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, zsh

Working on zsh on MacOS...

I was wondering if there was a way to query files via an index # of the current directory. For example, if `ls` outputs:

```
folder1
folder2
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

I was wondering if there was a way to run a command such as `open $FILES[2]` to open `file1.txt` (assuming 0 index).

I noticed that the command `open *` opened all individual folders and files of the current directory (finder/default apps), but commands like `open *[0]` weren't recognized.

My end goal is to find an easy way to both open and pass files, whose names are particularly long to other programs. A screenshot for example typically has a long file name and if I wanted to pass to ImageMagik or something, I figured this sort of file reference would be most efficient.

I should mention I'd be willing to switch from zsh to bash if this were an option there.

Comment: Just a comment because I am not sure, but I don't think so since the number is actually part of the file name and not an index as a variable.

Comment: What is the _index number_ of a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files have no inherent ordering on the filesystem, though can be sorted
by name, modification time, or so forth; with ZSH you can select by say
the most (or least) recently modified, if you can remember (or tab
complete) on the single character flags involved:

```
% mkdir test
% cd test
% touch a
% touch b
% touch c
% print *(om[1])
c
% print *(Om[1])
a
% touch aa
% print *(om[1])
aa
% touch aaa
% print *(om[1])
aaa
```

By name is available but good luck counting to some file in the middle of the list (or maybe you're better at doing that math in your head than I am?):

```
% print *(on[1])
a
% print *(On[1])
c
% touch zzz
% print *(On[1])
zzz
```

Other sorting options are available, though besides the first or last
it's probably not very viable for selecting a random filename. To select
by a number you'd need software that would associate some number with
the files loaded into an array, then a means to input some number to
pick some filename. Doable, but maybe not the best interface. There are
tools like `fzf` that might be better at file selection.

Usually for long filenames one will enable tab completion in the shell.
Both `bash` and `zsh` support this, though it may require configuration.

Comment: I found the "*(Om[1])" command to be interesting. It quite literally did what I needed it to do via "open *(Om[1])". Though I think the best solution you mentioned is the tab completion. I just learned of the feature, and can see how it's would handle most situations where you don't want to type or paste a filename from current directory. Thanks for the detailed response!